# Make ghostscript-10 load fonts only once

Tags: fonts, ghostscript

In Debian-11/Bullseye, ghostscript loads fonts in my document only once:

```
bullseye$ gs -sOutputFile=page-%04d.png -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -r108 example.pdf   
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3 (2020-10-01)
Copyright (C) 2020 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 8154.
Page 1
Loading NimbusSans-Bold font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.53.3/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold... 4466348 2932264 35444440 32057018 4 done.
Page 2
Page 3
Page 4
Page 5
Page 6
Page 7
Page 8
...
```

However, in Debian-12/Bookworm, ghostscript is busy with reloading fonts more than with actual rendering:

```
bookworm$ gs -sOutputFile=page-%04d.png -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -r108 example.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 10.0.0 (2022-09-21)
Copyright (C) 2022 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 8154.
Page 1
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Page 2
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Page 3
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Helvetica-Bold (or substitute) from /usr/share/ghostscript/10.00.0/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
...
```

What changed between ghostscript-9 and ghostscript-10? How can I get back the old efficient performance of ghostscript-9? Ghostscript doc says, I might run the ghostscript instruction `loadallfonts` at initialization time, but I do not know how to do this and whether this actually solves my problem.

Comment: I tried `echo loadallfonts >init.gs; gs init.gs` in order to see, whether this instruction makes something useful. Ghostscript shows many attempts to load fonts and fails pretty often and finally quits with `Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 13
GPL Ghostscript 10.00.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`. This also happens with old Ghostscript-9.

Comment: What you really mean is that the old PDF interpreter only told you once that it was loading a substitute font, whereas the new one tells you each time. I don't believe there is an inefficiency here, beyond the multiple warnings. Can you show that the performance is lower ? The interpreter caches the loaded font internally, so even if it did 'reload' the font, it wouldn't be any less efficient than the old approach which cached the font in the PostScript environment (which is why it only warns you once).

Comment: You're also using an old version, the current version is 10.02.1. With 10.0.0 you can use either -dOLDPDF or -dNEWPDF=false (I forget which but it should be in the release notes) to use the old interpreter instead.

Comment: You are right, I observed a slow performance and attributed it to the font load messages. But it was already slow in gs-9. About 2s per page to render for a simply structured document with little content.

Comment: Hmm, well it may be not as simple as you expect by looking at the rendered output, or it may be something else. Can't say without looking at the PDF file I'm afraid. Pointless transparency (pure white or black alpha channels for example) is a good way to slow down PDF rendering.

Comment: Yes, the document contains transparency. I also see that -sDEVICE=ppm gives some speedup. So maybe PNG compression eats some time.

Comment: PNG is a slow output format, because it is compressed, so yes a non-compressed format will likely be quicker. A PDF file with transparency will be slower and use more resources than one without. I would **never** describe a PDF file which uses transparency as 'simply constructed' :-)